# How to get the indexPath of a cell when i use it

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, tableview, cell

i would like to get the indexPath of a cell which has a UITextField. Is it possible to get the indexPath of the current UITextField that we are using ?

If yes, it will be awesome to tell me, i'm getting crazy since 2 hours on it...

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
CGPoint location = [sender.superview convertPoint:sender.center toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
```

another option would be to go up the view hierarchy. Adjust for your own view hierarchy:

```
UIView *contentView = [textField superview];
UITableViewCell *cell = [contentView superview];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: The 2nd option will fail if the text field is not directly added to the cell's contentView. The 1st option doesn't have this problem.